# Using cPanel to setup SSH for MySQL

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, mysql

Using cPanel as the only way to access the server, is it possible to setup a connect to MySQL so I can administor the MySQL database remotely?  i.e using MySQL WorkBench?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Once logged into cPanel you need to go to the "Remote MySQL" page which you will find in the databases section of cPanel. From here you need to enter the IP which you will be accessing your database from remotely, you can get this by visiting here on the machine: http://www.nethosted.co.uk/check-ip.php

Once you have set this up it will allow you to connect remotely to the MySQL database typically, you would enter the server address as your website url or server IP, remote port would be default 3306, database name, database user and password are all ones that you set through the cPanel MySQL Databases page.

A few things to note, database name and database user will be prefixed with your cPanel username and an underscore, and you need to make sure you have added the user to the database which you can do at the bottom of the MySQL Databases page in cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways:

1. Enable mysql direct connexions from the outside (+firewalling rules if need)
2. Create a VPN or an SSH tunnel from the computer running workbench to the mysql server

for `2`, it consists in creating a local tunnel going to the server's mysql-port (which is locally allowed) and then specify workbench to user localhost at that given port as a server location.